# how to add rss feed in our website

Tags: asp.net, rss, feed

I m adding rss feed in out publish website which is related to advocate .

Comment: You're going to have provide more/clear information.  You mentioned publishing, is it published through a Content Management System (CMS) of some sort?

Comment: Are you asking how to provide an RSS feed or how to consume one (converting it to HTML to display on a website)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an XML file according to the RSS standard.

If you are using database driven website, you can manipulate a dynamic RSS feed from your DB. Assuming you are using PHP you can find the instruction on this link to create dynmic RSS feeds. http://www.broculos.net/tutorials/how_to_make_a_dynamic_rss_feed_in_php/20080324/en

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/22/Awesome-ASP.NET-2.0-RSS-Tool_2D00_Kit-Released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    Title: <a href="<%# XPath("link") %>"><%# XPath("title") %></a><br />
    Pulish Date: <%# XPath("pubDate") %><br />
    Description: <%# XPath("description") %>
    <hr />
</ItemTemplate>
```